# How do I mock a builder using Powermockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I have a class like so:

```
public class AmazonAPI {
    public AmazonS3 myMethod() {
        return AmazonS3EncryptionClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(var)
            .build();
    }
}
```

I am using Junit4, Mockito and Powermockito. How do I mock these builder methods?

Comment: Is `AmazonS3EncryptionClientBuilder` your code? If not, why even test it? Just mock `AmazonAPI` and be done with it. For testing `AmazonAPI`, just check that the returned Builder has the region and other attributes you want.

Comment: The answer is almost always "don't". I've never once had to resort to Powermockito.

Comment: @Robert It's not my code. The reason is because when it executes it will access some external database.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- So you never once ever used a static method that accessed external resources?

Comment: @Robert Also, I'm confused about what you mean. Me not wanting to test it exactly means I should mock it so that it's not executed.

Comment: @Goldname there are other ways of avoiding static methods that don't involve resorting to PowerMockito.

Comment: Correct. Static methods _shouldn't do that_. (Or, more specifically, they should not operate on resources that were not passed to them as parameters.)